# Would a file upload controller gain performance benefits if converted to an AsyncController?

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous

I have a controller action which handles multiple photo uploads (which are uploaded using [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/)).  For each file that is uploaded, the controller will do the following:

- Create 7 resized versions of the photo
- Upload these 7 versions to Amazon S3
- Save info about the photo into a database.

The end user of this web app will be uploading as many as 100 hi res (~4mb) photos at a time so performance is a priority.

In this scenario, would I see an increase in performance (i.e. total time spent waiting for the app to handle the uploads) if I changed the controller to an AsyncController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably won't increase performance but it might offload some worker threads especially while waiting for the upload on the Amazon S3 servers which is a IO bound task and you could benefit from I/O completion ports. As far as the resizing is concerned that's CPU bound task so there's not much you could do about it other than improving the algorithm.

Comment: So multiple simultaneous uploads to Amazon S3 would be the place I would see benefit as far as total execution time is concerned?

Comment: @jessegavin, you won't benefit from any total time: asynchronous controllers still block and the user have to wait. But due to I/O Completion Ports the overall performance of other actions could increase as you will be freeing worker threads. Here's a nice article you might read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx

Comment: Thanks so much Darin. I will leave this question open for a bit for other answers. I appreciate it.